# What is the advantage in reducing variables in vb6?

Tags: vb6

I have a code written in VB6.
There I have some variable which can be removed by some code manipulation?
Is there any advantage of removing one or two extra variables?

Comment: It'll be less code that you have to migrate to .NET? :)

Comment: plus you pay less variable tax.

Comment: If you're thinking about removing variables by reusing existing variables, you should get that silly little thought out of your head.

Comment: Very hard to answer this question without seeing some specific example code

Answer (score 5):

Instead of removing variables (how else do you refer to anything?) just reduce their scope.

Answer (score 0):

There are generally two reasons given for removing local variables.

1. The program uses a little less
   memory, this is very minor and not
   the reason to remove the variables.
2. The code becomes a lot a clenaer,
   easier to read and a lot less
   complex. (This is the real reason to remove the variables).

Since (especially true with VB6) maintenance is where you spend 90% of your time programming, its worth making your life a little easier.

Answer (score 0):

By removing variables the code MAY look more clean, but not necessarily more readable.

Advantages:

1. less memory
2. more speed

However, I would not worry about it much, unless it is inside a loop. You should clear up variables not really required inside a loop